# Redirect URL to an existing page with query string or #! added on

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to make a photo gallery where the individual photos can be shared on Facebook and Twitter, and when you click the link, the photo that was shared will open in a lightbox automatically.

Most lightbox plugins provide a deep-linking feature that provides this in the form of a #! after the URL. Unfortunately, both the Facebook (https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://google.com) and Twitter (http://twitter.com/share?text=My%20Tweet&url=http://google.com) share boxes strip out all text after the #. This means that when you try to share a deep-linked lightbox photo, the link just brings you back to the gallery rather than opening that photo.

The non-WordPress solution I came up with was to share a static URL and then use a RewriteRule to send them to the correct place. So for example, the user would share "example.com/gallery/123/" on Facebook, and when they went there they would be sent to "example.com/gallery/?photo=123". This would be parsed by Javascript to programmatically click on the correct image and open the lightbox.

The RewriteRule I came up with:

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/(.*)/$ /gallery/?photo=$1 [R]
```

Does work fine on a static site, but not in WordPress, which is why I'm here!

I'd prefer the URL to be /gallery/#!/123, but I know you can't add a #! with RewriteRule, so if anyone can think of a way to do that, it'd be even better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way you could do this with an internal WordPress rewrite, which would then set a query var you could check when enqueueing your javascript, and pass that data via [localize script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

so first, rewrite rule to intercept requests to `gallery/` with something appended, load the page named `gallery`, and set the query var `gallery_id` to whatever was in the URL. also we add the `gallery_id` query var so WordPress knows about it. Make sure to visit permalinks settings page after adding the rewrite, to flush rules and this new rule.

```
function wpa_gallery_rewrite(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'gallery/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=gallery&gallery_id=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa_gallery_rewrite' );

function wpa_gallery_query_var( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'gallery_id';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'wpa_gallery_query_var');
```

Now when we enqueue our javascript, we can check for that value and set a var which will be added along with the script and available to it.

```
function wpa_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'wpa_script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my_gallery.js',
        array('jquery'),
        null,
        false
    );
    $default_photo = ( get_query_var( 'gallery_id' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'gallery_id' ) : 0;
    wp_localize_script(
        'wpa_script',
        'wpa_data',
        array(
            'default_photo' => $default_photo
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa_scripts', 100 );
```

Now in your javascript, check `wpa_data.default_photo` to see if it equals 0, or there was a specific photo requested.